# Fill a PDF with the input details obtained from a react app

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I am building a React.js application which takes some input like name, age, email etc from the users and I need to fill these data into a Form 11 PDF and enable users to download the filled PDF. So basically a slight automation software for form 11. So far I have obtained the data from users and have stored it in variables using the useState hook. How can I fill these data onto the respective spaces in a Form 11 PDF. Welp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) is an option. Its very very simple to implement.

Fill form official example: https://pdf-lib.js.org/#fill-form

Another option is [pdfform.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfform.js)

Comment: Bro is there any way to download the pdf I have saved.  As shown in pdf-lib documentation I have done const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save(). So the PDF is saved in 'pdfBytes' variable. How can I build a button so that a user can download this PDF. Or even better, auto download the PDF into the local system of the user. Btw thank you so much for the help

Comment: Create a new question so I can answer there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328873/how-to-download-a-file-stored-as-bytes-in-a-react-javascript-variable

Answer (score 1):

Okay, It is easy if you use Annotation component in react-pdf module.

[image]

Hope this helps you.